# Jersey The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes

Tags: java, jersey

#### This is not a duplicated question, because the answers that are listed in other questions didn't work with me

This is the exception that I am having

> com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.

according to other questions, I have to set this property

```
com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig
```

and I actually did, as you see:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MMS-Client</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>mypackage.servlets</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MMS-Client</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mmsclient/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The package is there, so why do I am having this error?

This is the signature of my class also

```
@Path("om" + "/mms")
public class class1 extends Class2 {

    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String test() {
        return "test";
    }
```

And this is the pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.18</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.18</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Not related but you should be not using the Jersey 2.x multipart. Use [this instead](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey.contribs/jersey-multipart/1.18)

Comment: Too lazy to test, but what happens if you get completely rid of the first init-param `com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass`